# Horizontal line in a pbox

Tags: rules

While creating a quiz, I needed to format logical arguments, which our textbook presents as a list of premises, one per line, then a horizontal rule as wide as the widest premise, and the conclusion underneath.  There should not be too much space around the rule (it does not take up a line of its own.)

I dealt with this by using the `pbox` package (I have version 1.2.) I put the premises and conclusion in a pbox, with an `\hrule` before the conclusion.  Since the `\pbox` was the width of the widest line, the `\hrule` was also the right width. Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pbox}
\begin{document}
\pbox{8cm}{
Either you love logic or you hate it. \\
You don't hate logic.
\smallskip\hrule\smallskip
You love logic.}
\end{document}
```

This works fine, actually, except that it produces an error: `` You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders. ``  After pressing enter to ignore the error, it is output exactly as I would hope, except that having to press enter 9 times each time I compile my document is not very nice.  The quiz looks like this:

[image: Logical Arguments]

This raises a 4-fold question:

1. What is the reason for the error, which only seems to arise in a `\pbox`?  I would love an explanation of the TeXnical underpinnings.
2. How should one draw a horizontal line across a `\pbox` without error?
   I found that `\hrulefill` works, but needs its own line.
   Is there a more elegant way than `\\[-.7em] \null\hrulefill\\[-.2em]`,
   which has the disadvantage of fiddly spacing (liable to break down,
   and only approximating the spacing of `\smallskip\hrule\smallskip`, which I liked)?
3. Is there a way to use `\leaders`, as suggested by the error, to maintain the same output
   produced by `\hrule` but without the error?
4. What's the proper way to achieve my desired result?
   I suppose the obvious method is with a `tabular` environment, but this does not seem semantically correct to me.
   A succession of statements, with a line underneath, is not a table!
   Also, the line does not fit the width quite as nicely as it does in a `\pbox`, though I'm sure that can be fixed with fiddling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing only item 4, hiding the `tabular` inside a macro `\logicarg{<premise>}{<conclusion>}` might be more appealing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\logicarg}[2]{% \logicarg{<premise>}{<conclusion>}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    #1 \\ \hline #2
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \logicarg
    {If you are eating soup then I am happy. \\ You are eating soup}
    {I am happy}
  \item \logicarg
    {If it is Wednesday then you aren't taking a quiz. \\ It is not Wednesday.}
    {You are taking a quiz.}
  \item \logicarg
    {Either you love logic or you hate it. \\ You don't hate logic.}
    {You love logic.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer, since it's the method I'll actually use, but David's answer addresses parts 1, 2, and 3.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pbox}
\begin{document}
\pbox{8cm}{
Either you love logic or you hate it. \\
You don't hate logic.
\smallskip
\endgraf
\ifvmode\nointerlineskip\fi
\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1pt \hfill\mbox{}\endgraf
\smallskip
You love logic.}



\end{document}
```

You can't use `\vrule` in vertical mode and you can't use `\hrule` in horizontal mode but it's a bit delicate on pbox as it measures things in hmode first and then sets a paragraph. `\pbox` is mostly a tabular environment it would be simpler to use one directly for this usage probably.

Comment: your syntax in the last sentence is rather tortured.  i'd edit it, but i'm not entirely sure how to keep your meaning.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes it was 3 in the morning:-)

Comment: Wow—I guess that answers #3, and it's ugly enough to make using `tabular` more palatable! ;-) Although, it doesn't quite reproduce the behavior of the error-producing `\smallskip\hrule\smallskip`—there's more space left afterwards, even if I remove the second `\smallskip` in your code.  I didn't realize that `\pbox` is built with `tabular`; knowing that makes Werner's solution all the better.